# Swift constraints issue when using custom segue

Tags: swift, layout, constraints, segue, transition

I am using custom segue to present a view controller, it works fine when I don't use any constraint, once I add a constraint to the label on the destination view controller, then it pops up an error saying:

> "negative sizes are not supported in the flow layout"

[image: Segue]

This is my custom segue code

```swift
class PresentTimeMachineSegue: UIStoryboardSegue {
    
    override func perform() {
        destination.transitioningDelegate = self
        destination.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
        source.present(destination, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

extension PresentTimeMachineSegue: UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate {
    public func animationController(forPresented presented: UIViewController, presenting: UIViewController, source: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
        return TimeMachineViewPresentAnimationController()
    }
        
    public func animationController(forDismissed dismissed: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
        return TimeMachineViewPresentAnimationController()
    }
}

class TimeMachineViewPresentAnimationController: NSObject, UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning {
    
   
    func transitionDuration(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning?) -> TimeInterval {
        return 0.5
    }
    
    func animateTransition(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {
CalendarViewController
        let containerView = transitionContext.containerView
        let toViewController = transitionContext.viewController(forKey: .to) as! TimeMachineViewController
        

        print("transition")
        if toViewController.calendarView != nil {

            //toViewController.view.addSubview(toViewController.calendarView!)
            containerView.addSubview(toViewController.view)
            toViewController.inlitializeUI()
        }
        
        toViewController.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white.withAlphaComponent(0)
        
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.8, animations: {
            toViewController.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white.withAlphaComponent(1)
        }) { _ in
            
            transitionContext.completeTransition(true)
 
        }
        
        
    }
    
    
}
```

[image: Error]